# Passwords do not match in ddlcient setup

Tags: 16.04, server, password, configuration, ddclient

Every time I install a new ubuntu server, I add ddclient (via apt-get)

Since some time, I don't exactly remember when it started, but for sure every time I used 16.04. I get a 'Passwords do not match"-message from ddclient.

During setup of ddclient I'm asked which service I want to use.
After selecting DynDns, I enter username and password (twice), at which point I'm asked if I want to select the device 'from a list' among other options.

Since when selecting 'from a list' I get a list of all hosts I have configured in DynDns, the passwords I entered should be correct (Right?).

After selecting a host, which seems to work, I get a prompt telling me the passwords did not match. After entering the password again no additional prompt shows up.

The first 2-3 times this happened, I doubted myself, but after 10+ times I don't think it's my fault …

Does anyone know something about this or can tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

## Edit the `ddclient` configuration file manually

I found the configuration setup of `ddclient` to be a little basic and it did not give me the choices I wanted. I ended up editing the configuration file manually. To do this open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
pkexec gedit /etc/ddclient.conf
```

Note: you should `pkexec` instead of `sudo` or `gksudo` for GUI applications like gedit. If you are trying this on a non-GUI environment, use sudo and your preferred text editor, such as `vim`, or `nano`.

Now you can comment out the lines created during installation and put in your own setting.

To determine what you should put in the configuration file look at:

1. [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DynamicDNS#ddclient) and
2. [DynDNS help](https://help.dyn.com/ddclient/)

I use a different DNS server, so I can't help with the exact configuration. But this is what I think should work:

```
# Basic configuration file for ddclient
#
# /etc/ddclient.conf
daemon=3600                 # This will check at 1 hour interval
use=web, web=checkip.dyndns.com/, web-skip='IP Address'
login=your-username      # Your user ID for logging in dydns.org
password='your-password' # Your password for logging in dydns.org you may need the single quotes  
protocol=dyndns2
server=members.dyndns.org
wildcard=YES
pits_pc.dyndns.org          # Replace this with your personal URL
```

Once you have edited the configuration file, use this command to verify that `ddclient` is working correctly:

```
sudo ddclient -daemon=0 -debug -verbose -noquiet
```

Hope this helps